# Stuck at the floating continent in the first part of the game

Tags: final-fantasy-6

Once about half way in, I walked back, since things started to get hard. I went back all the way to the starting point to put up a tent. Now I cannot find my way forward. I can get to the first "teleport" pad and past this a way opens to the monster in a box. Through the teleport there are 2 short dead ends. I have been wandering around for an hour inside this small area, there is no way further it seems.

Where do I go next?

Comment: Are you certain thy're dead ends? I believe for one of them you can walk "through" the foreground scenery. It might be worth looking up a walkthrough video of the floating continent. Its hard to tell exactly where you're stuck from your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you use the first teleport pad, you should head south and look for a switch on the wall (I think near a set of stairs). Using the switch should reveal another teleport pad on that section of the floating continent that will allow you to go further. There are 2 or 3 more instances on the floating continent where you must find and activate a switch (2 switches in one case) in order to proceed.

Comment: What you talk about is a bit further on the continent but it actually helped me. After the first teleport pad there is a switch you can stand on. It looked like an empty chest, a desaturated blue orb. When i stepped on it a wall opened up, i cannot believe i missed this for so long.It was because i already ventured there and misplaced it for a chest.